# Built-in base class for controllers in ASP.NET MVC: Controller or ControllerBase?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

What is the built-in base class for controllers in ASP.NET MVC:

System.Web.Mvc.Controller or System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase?

It is unclear to me after searching on Google:

1. On [www.ASP.NET](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/aspnet-mvc-controllers-overview-cs): " A controller is a class that derives from the base System.Web.Mvc.Controller class."
2. On [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/590576/Understanding-the-IController-and-ControllerBase-i): "The abstract ControllerBase class represents the base class for all MVC controllers."
3. On MSDN: "The base class for all controllers is the ControllerBase class, which provides general MVC handling. The Controller class inherits from ControllerBase and is the default implement of a controller."
4. In the book "Pro ASP.NET MVC 5 Framework" from Adam Freeman: "In ASP.NET MVC, controllers are just C# classes (usually inheriting from System.Web.Mvc.Controller, the framework's built-in controller base class)."

Who is right? What does "Built-in base class" mean exactly in this context?
Is "Controller" the built-in base class and "ControllerBase" the ???? (what would be the right wording?) base class?

Comment: Try creating a random controller and see yourself :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`Controller` is the class you should derive from to implement your own MVC controllers. `ControllerBase` is derived by `Controller` and, like any abstract class, it doesn't provide implementations to some members that `Controller` does.

In addition, `Controller` has many more members than `ControllerBase` (for example, it lacks `View()` and many others you may be get used to call in your regular controllers!).

Actually, `ControllerBase` is an infrastructure class, and it's not suitable to be used directly to implement your own controllers.

Answer (score 16):

By Defination

ControllerBase : A base class for an MVC controller without view support.

Controller : A base class for an MVC controller with view support.

Thus if we are not creating views i.e. creating Web API use ControllerBase else use Controller.

Comment: This is the correct answer and should be the accepted one

Comment: Good rule of thumb is: `Object → ControllerBase → Controller`, from documentation. Readings: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.controllerbase?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.controller?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2

Answer (score 1):

ASP MVC requires that all controllers implement `IController` interface. A controller doesn't need to derive from `Controller` or `ControllerBase` class.

You can find an example of a custom controller implementing the `IController` interface in Adam Freeman's book.

`ControllerBase` class implements `IController` interface and adds several methods and properties (e.g. `ViewBag`). It defines an abstract `ExecuteCore` method that is responsible for locating the action method and executing it. If you choose to derive your controller from `ControllerBase`, you will have to provide implementation for this method.

`Controller` class derives from `ControllerBase`. It provides an implementation for `ExecuteCore` method and adds several useful methods you can use in your controllers (for example `View()`, `Redirect()` etc.).

To summarize - both `ControllerBase` and `Controller` are built-in base classes for controllers. Built-in, because they are part of the ASP.NET MVC framework. Base classes for controllers, because if you derive from them, you will create a controller.

Answer (score 0):

`Controller` class is a wrapper over `ControllerBase` that provides built in functionality for a regular use of the framework especially methods for dealing with HTTP requests.

You can look at the `ControllerBase` as a class the specifies the minimum requirements that a controller needs to do. It implements the IController interface which has the Execute action. This is the basic functionality that a controller should do from the framework point of view: executing incoming requests.

For normal users the choice is definitely `Controller` which inherits from `ControllerBase` and has all the build in support for a regular use.

Comment: Why a *wrapper*? Can inheritance implement wrapper pattern at all?

Comment: Maybe the word wrapper was not the best fit here, i didn't mean in the default sense of the word, i was just trying to underline that it extends the ControllerBase which contains the minimum logic that a controller should have, but it extends it with many functions required for a regular use of the framework.

Comment: I'll give you a hint: replace the word *wrapper* with **specialization**.

Answer (score 0):

I find myself having trouble posting values a Controller inheriting the ControllerBase class from fetch or axios and having to use APIController instead for the versatile and intuitive functionality that makes me not want to rip my hair out.