# IController vs ControllerBase vs Controller vs MyController?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oop

I have an ASP.NET MVC project I have been building and was looking through some documentation when I came across how the Controller class is implemented. I am pretty familiar with OOP but have a few questions about why it is implemented in such a manner.

I looked on [codeproject](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/560798/ASP-NET-MVC-controller-dependency-injection-for-be) and some [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32926724/built-in-base-class-for-controllers-in-asp-net-mvc-controller-or-controllerbase) questions but couldn't find quite the same question I am wondering.

1. in MVC 5 What is the purpose of this chain: IController -> ControllerBase -> Controller -> MyController.
2. If ControllerBase is supposed to be the minimum it takes to make a controller then why have a Controller class? Or vise versa if Controller is the minimum implementation then ControllerBase isn't really a base class?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That is a question for the developers themselves, making it rather broad and primarily opinion based for this site.

Comment: Refer also [Built-in base class for controllers in ASP.NET MVC: Controller or ControllerBase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32926724/built-in-base-class-for-controllers-in-asp-net-mvc-controller-or-controllerbase)

Comment: @Nkosi im not sure what the stack overflow protocol is for a question on hold.I have marked the submission below as answer but I agree that it would be a good question for the developers and that its rather a matter of opinion.

StephenMuecke thanks for your resources ill look into them today.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

In MVC 5, `ControllerBase` only acts simply like a base class for mostly internal usage and internally implements the `IController.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)`, and here is the list of usages I got from Resharper
[image]

The `Controller` then implements all of the features for filters, model and view binding. Therefore, to implement your `MyController`, you need to derive from `Controller`

Your SO [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32926724/built-in-base-class-for-controllers-in-asp-net-mvc-controller-or-controllerbase) already explained the purpose of `ControllerBase` and `Controller`.

Thing look a lot more interesting in MVC 6 (subsequently called ASP.NET MVC Core) when ASP.NET team converged MVC, WebAPI into one framework

Please look at the source code for the Controller and ControllerBase class in GitHub for ASP.NET Core 1.1.1. In the `<summary>` tag for each class, they say:

[Controler.cs](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/rel/1.1.1/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures/Controller.cs)

> A base class for an MVC controller **with** view support.

[ControllerBase.cs](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/rel/1.1.1/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/ControllerBase.cs)

> A base class for an MVC controller **without** view support.

You may ask when to use ControllerBase. My instinct tells me that if I only use ASP.NET MVC for WebAPI and doesn't require the `View` feature, you could derive your `MyController` directly from `ControllerBase`. Most of the time, you could derive from `Controller` even if you don't use `View` and only return string or JSON for WebAPI. `Controller.cs` allows you to return a `View` and take advantage of the auto binding.

Comment: thanks for your answer, it went a long way into clarifying the differences. The question is now on hold because perhaps its a matter of opinion as to why it was implemented that way. Either way Ill mark as answer.