# Why I can't use Viebag in class

Tags: .net, model-view-controller

Why I can't use ViewBag in class.

The name "ViewBag" does not exist in the current context

I use it to store the value

```
       if (searchString != null)
            {
                page = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                searchString = currentFilter;
            }

            ViewBag.CurrentFilter = searchString;
```

Using what I use

```cs
using Shop.Data.Migrations.IServices;
using Shop.Data.Models;
using Shop.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Web.Mvc;
```

This is not a controller class

Comment: My understanding is that `ViewBag` is usually a *property* of a controller or a page, not a type. You haven't shown how you're trying to use it, or from what class, but I'd expect you to be able to use it as a property in the right place. Please give more context if that doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** `Your Controller class must derives from ControllerBase` to use ViewBag

`ViewBag` belongs to `System.Web.Mvc` namespace.

`ViewBag` is dynamic property belongs to `ControllerBase` abstract class.

> ControllerBase class implements IController interface and adds several
>   methods and properties (e.g. ViewBag). It defines an abstract
>   ExecuteCore method that is responsible for locating the action method
>   and executing it. If you choose to derive your controller from
>   ControllerBase, you will have to provide implementation for this
>   method.
>
> Controller class derives from ControllerBase. It provides an
>   implementation for ExecuteCore method and adds several useful methods
>   you can use in your controllers (for example View(), Redirect() etc.).
>
> To summarize - both ControllerBase and Controller are built-in base
>   classes for controllers. Built-in, because they are part of the
>   ASP.NET MVC framework. Base classes for controllers, because if you
>   derive from them, you will create a controller.

[Above copied from this link to give you more idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32926724/built-in-base-class-for-controllers-in-asp-net-mvc-controller-or-controllerbase)

Sample

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
namespace Sample.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public void Upload(string searchString)
        {
            if (searchString != null)
            {
                page = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                searchString = currentFilter;
            }

            ViewBag.UploadError = "Upload file error";

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
```

should be enough to use ViewBage in your Controller class:

```
ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";
```

Could you provide us more information?

Comment: I do not use it in the controller class I have  ```using System.Web.Mvc;```

Comment: Where are you using it? Does your class extend from Controller?